# system.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException : Could not find a part of the path ( android build in unity )

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

im working on unity3d application for android and im trying to move uploaded file from user dir to Application.persistentDataPath in android using File.Move, it works fine in windows, but after i exported it to android, it give me this Error

> system.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException : Could not find a part of the path

here's the code im working on

```
FileBrowser.ShowLoadDialog( (path) => {
        var temp = path.Split('\\');
        string filename = "";
        foreach (var item in temp)
        {
            filename = item;
        }
        // Path.Combine(path);
        var dir = Application.persistentDataPath + "/upload";

        if (!Directory.Exists(dir)) 
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir); // create /Upload dir

            return;
        }else{
            Debug.Log("That path exists already.");
        }

        try{ 
            //Move the selected file
            File.Move(path,dir + '/' + filename); 
            Debug.Log(dir + '/' + filename);
            text.GetComponent<Text>().text = dir + '/' + filename;
        }catch(Exception e){
            text.GetComponent<Text>().text = e.ToString();
        }

        // FileUtil.MoveFileOrDirectory(path, Application.persistentDataPath + '/' + filename);
         }, 
                                   () => { Debug.Log( "Canceled" ); }, 
                                   false, null, "Select Folder", "Select" );

}
```

can someone help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't use string concatentation `+` and `/` for getting system paths.

Rather always use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) which automatically uses the correct path separator according to the target platform.

also where you use `path.Split('\\');` this might work on Windows where the path separator is `\` but maybe not on Android where the path separator is usually `/` so rather use either `split` with [`Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar)

doing it in a loop is quite redundand and even if you rather want to use `Split` for whatever reason you would be more efficient simply doing somthing like

```
var temp = path.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
var filename = temp[temp.Count - 1];
```

or rather simply directly use [`Path.GetFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename) which returns only the filename component of a given path.

```
FileBrowser.ShowLoadDialog(
    (path) => 
    {
        var temp = Path.GetFileName(path);
        var dir = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "upload");

        if (!Directory.Exists(dir)) 
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir); // create /Upload dir
            // WHY DO YOU RETURN HERE?
           //return;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("That path exists already.");
        }

        try
        { 
            //Move the selected file
            var filePath = Path.Combine(dir, filename);
            File.Move(path, filePath); 
            Debug.Log(filePath);
            text.GetComponent<Text>().text = filePath;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            text.GetComponent<Text>().text = e.ToString();
        }
     }, 
     () => { Debug.Log( "Canceled" ); }, 
     false, 
     null, 
     "Select Folder", 
     "Select"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when save the project in drive with very long path name, then this error occurs, I don't remember but there is a limit of characters for path name, I have saved my project in folders within folders ,when I cut the project from from sub folders and pasted in main folder then the path size reduced and the again added the project in unity and opened ,there was no error then.